# C# return a List of a variable child class?

Tags: c#, json

Newbie at C# here -

I have a JSON data source that I can query. Depending on the query I issue, that JSON interface can return more than one type of object. e.g. it could return a list of `Customers`, or a list of `Vendors`, or a list of `Items`, or etc. etc. etc.

All of these objects can inherit from one base class.

Is there a way to have a single C# method able to return a list of variable type?

What about if I'm returning just a single Customer, or a single Vendor. Is there a way to make a single `->get(type, id)` method return any of those object types depending on the `type` I pass in?

Comment: could you provide that query ?

Comment: public TYPE Get<TYPE>(id)
{
}

Comment: It's a remote JSON API - you can send it SQL-like queries:  "FETCH Customers WHERE Balance > 0"

Answer (score 2):

As AD.Net already said, you can make a generic method.

Something like

```
public T GetData<T>(String query)
{
    T data = //query stuff here
    return data;
}
```

Now, if you want to query with a query that returns a list of `Customer`:

```
var list = GetList<List<Customer>>("customerquery");
```

To query for a single Vendor:

```
var v = GetList<Vendor>("vendor query");
```

Etc etc..

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are looking for [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

```
public T Get<T>(object id)
{
    var type = typeof(T);

    // construct your query based on the type
    // var queryResult = ...
    return JsonLibrary.Parse<T>(queryResult);
}
var customer = Get<Customer>("ben");
var vendors = Get<List<Vendor>>("ben&jerrys");
```